# SOAP, usernameToken issue

Tags: web-services, soap, soap-client

and need to know few things as I am getting Internal error from server and I think it is related how am I generating Header port of SOAP.

Here is how it should look like:

```
<soapenv:Header>

<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-CA07017CE54cDFC14720230904344">

<wsse:Username>test</wsse:Username>

<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">******</wsse:Password>

<wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">xgy3s2Owe4zUNGc/2t3twA==</wsse:Nonce>

<wsu:Created>2016-08-24T07:18:10.434Z</wsu:Created>

</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

ok, so:
- username is username :)
- password is cleardText from what I can see 
- Nonce I am generating like this: 
var nonce = new Date().getTime() * 1000;
nonce = new Buffer(nonce.toString()).toString('base64'); (Nodejs)
- And date is generated like below in sample.

My questions:
- UsernameToken ID: how this is generated? Must this be presented?

If my SOAP request looks like this, is this ok:

```
<soap:Header>
<wsse:UsernameToken>
<wsse:Password>1231231</<wsse:Password>
<wsse:Nonce>1232132131</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2016-08-24T07:18:10.434Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</soap:Header>
```

Or must I put all http stuff end etc?

thank you very much!
MIha

Comment: The beginning of your question seems to be missing. What SOAP service are you connecting to?

Comment: Hi, it is ibm soap sevice/server. I hope i answered your question. If you were asking something else please let me know.